# Nested Category Layout alternative?

Tags: woocommerce

Is there any Nested Category Layout alternative?

For example. My subcategories are displayed in this way
[Screenshot](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/woocommerce-typical-subcategories.png)

But I want to achieve something like this

[screenshot](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/woocommerce-nested-category-layout-after-550x538.png)

Is there any free alternative out there or maybe simple custom code that would solved my problem?